# How can I use C++ to update an SQLite row relative to its original value?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to update a row in a table in an SQLite database using C++, but I want to update it relative to its current value.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int val=argv[2]; 
string bal = "UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + " + argv[1] + "WHERE account_id = " + bal + argv[2];


if (sqlite3_open("bank.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_prepare( db, balance.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL );//preparing the statement
    sqlite3_step( stmt );//executing the statement
}
```

So that the first parameter is the account_id, and the second parameter is the current balance.
However, this does not work. What can I do to have the database successfully update?

Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. The primary situation is having a table with many entries, each with a unique account id. For example, one has an id of 1 with a balance of 5.

If I run this program with the parameters "1 5", the balance should now be 10. If I run it again with "1 7", it should be 17.

Comment: I seems that your question can be solved completely in `SQL` field, but explain please more clearly what result are you trying to get

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like "UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE account_id = 42"?

Comment: Updated! @SergeyLebedev

Comment: Yes exactly @latedeveloper, but dynamically, so we don't know balance, the amount added, or account_id. Thank you!

Comment: So just substitute your command line parameters for "100" and "42" in the statement in my previous comment.

Comment: @latedeveloper that did not work, but thanks! I updated my question with that attempt in the code instead of my original one. Is that what you had meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the + operator to concatenate C-style strings and string literals. A quick and dirty fix:

```
string bal = string("UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + ") + argv[1] + string( " WHERE account_id = " ) + argv[2];
```

Comment: You should also mention the space you added before `WHERE`.

Comment: @Barmar I made several other changes. I did not intend this to be identical with the OP's code. Also, it's considered rude to tell people what they "should" do, better is to say "you could have".